# How to get updated prop from parent after forcing a method call in Vue js?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a event emmiter that forces API call in the parent:

Parent component

```
<ProductChild
        :productId="productId"
        @update="getProduct()"
        :product="product"
       
      ></ProductChild>
```

Child component

```
 props: {
    product: {
      type: Object,
    },
    }

methods: {
updateProductTag(){
 this.$emit('update')
arait this.productItem = this.product
}
}
```

It seems the child forces the api call in Parent but I don't get the updated prop in the child. What is wrong and how can I by forcing that method call in parent also pass new prop and use that updated prop in the child?

Comment: If `getProduct` doesn't change one of the props passed to the child, then there would be no new data in the child.  You didn't show that method so we don't know what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch for the prop. There is no warranty that after emit you get the changes immediately.

```
 props: {
    reportId: {
      type: Number,
    },
    product: {
      type: Object,
    },
},
watch:{
  product(){
    this.productItem = this.product
    // after product has updated
  }
},

methods: {
 updateProductTag(){
   this.$emit('update')
  // arait this.productItem = this.product
 }
}
```

It is better to do "getProduct()" in the child component and pass the result to the parent by:

```
this.$emit('update:product', theResultOfGetProduct)
```

and catch it in the parent by sync:

```
<ProductChild
  :productId="productId"
  :product.sync="product"       
></ProductChild>
```